# Checking multiple data frame columns at once (flexible manner)

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization, apply

Looking for a better way: How can I make R check the values of a flexible subset of multiple columns element-wise (let's say `Var2` and `Var3` here) and write the result of the check to a new logical column?

Is there a shorter, more elegant way than using row-wise `apply()` here?

```
df <- read.csv(
  text = '"Var1","Var2","Var3"
  "","",""
  "","","a"
  "","a",""
  "a","a","a"
  "a","","a"
  "","a",""
  "","",""
  "","","a"
  "","a",""
  "","","a"'
)

criticalColumns <- c("Var2", "Var3")

df$criticalColumnsAreEmpty <-
  apply(df[, criticalColumns], 1, function(curRow) {
    return(all(curRow == ""))
  })
```

I could also do this in an explicit way, but this is not a flexible then:

```
df$criticalColumnsAreEmpty <- df$Var2 == "" & df$Var3 == ""
```

Desired output:

```
 Var1 Var2 Var3 criticalColumnsAreEmpty
                                   TRUE
              a                   FALSE
         a                        FALSE
    a    a    a                   FALSE
    a         a                   FALSE
         a                        FALSE
                                   TRUE
              a                   FALSE
         a                        FALSE
              a                   FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on the logical matrix

```
df$criticalColumnsAreEmpty <- !rowSums(df[criticalColumns]!="")
df$criticalColumnsAreEmpty
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or another option (for big datasets to avoid converting to matrix for memory reasons) is loop over the columns, check whether the elements are blank and use `Reduce` with `&`

```
Reduce(`&`, lapply(df[criticalColumns], function(x) !nzchar(as.character(x))))
```